# Google maps not loading in ie 9

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i'm trying to get http://www.zimmi.cz/mapa/mapa.html work in IE 9. It works just fine in Opera, Chrome, Firefox and compatibility mode of IE 9, but not IE 9 itself. The map doesn't load at all, but i can't find reason why.
Developer Tools says "SCRIPT5039: const was already declared" (translated from Czech) on line 24 char 1, which is jquery $().ready(function(). If anyone can help me out, i'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```